# Passing callback into tokio task

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I have a function that takes a callback as a parameter:

```
fn my_function (on_complete: Box<dyn FnOnce(bool)) {
    // Do some work
    on_complete(false);
}
```

The work I do before calling is pretty heavy though, so I'm trying to spawn it off into a task:

```
fn my_function (on_complete: Box<dyn FnOnce(bool)) {
    tokio::spawn(async move{
        // Do some work
        on_complete(false);
    });
}
```

This is giving me all sorts of ownership issues, namely that my Box can't be safely shared across threads. I've tried a number of things to get around this, including obvious ones like borrowing and more traditional threading solutions like passing it as an Arc>, but can't seem to get anywhere.

Any suggestions on how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mark your boxed callback as thread-safe with `Send`:

```rust
fn my_function (on_complete: Box<dyn FnOnce(bool) + Send>) {
//                                               ^^^^^^^
    tokio::spawn(async move{
        // Do some work
        on_complete(false);
    });
}
```

Comment: This was indeed it!  Such a simple answer as well!  For future readers, this is detailed here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch16-04-extensible-concurrency-sync-and-send.html